# Files downloading instead of opening in Chrome

Tags: excel, chrome

User is accessing SP through Chrome (rest of us have IE). When they click on a spreadsheet they don't get the usual prompt to select read only/edit mode. The spreadsheet opens and they make their changes. when they hit save the spreadsheet is saved as file `name[1].xl` in their downloads folder.

How can I make it so they can edit the document and save it back to SharePoint? There are no SP metadata fields visible and they can't Save As and select SharePoint

Think I might have answered  this myself. when the user selects the drop down on the spreadsheet and clicks "Edit in Microsoft Office Excel" they get the following error

> "Edit Document" requires a Windows SharePoint Services compatible application and Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0 or greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way Chrome handles file downloads. Google decided that rather than allowing applications to automatically open files downloaded through Chrome, the files must be downloaded to your local machine. There is, unfortunately, no workaround for this. If you want to automatically open files from Sharepoint to be worked in and saved back up to SP within the browser, you'll need to use a different browser like IE or Firefox.

However, if you simply want the file to download *and* automatically open the application, see the answer by Tekla.  After downloading, you'll click the up arrow / caret (^) next to the download on the status bar, and choose "Always open files of this type".  This will cause Chrome to pass the download over to the associated application.

Answer (score 1):

Set the OpenInClient feature for a document library or site collection as mentioned [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx)

Comment: This looks like it could work but I don't think I have the powers and it's for 2013

Answer (score 1):

OpenInClient feature  doesn't do anything for you if you use Chrome. The document is still downloaded when you try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link to the excel document (in chrome)
At the bottom left, you’ll see the spreadsheet icon as it downloads.  Instead of clicking to open, click on the little arrow to the right and select "Always open files of this type".

You’ll have to do this for each file type.

Comment: Did you mean "can't"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open in the web browser and add sheet protection in the document.  I use Chrome with the IE Tab add on with auto URL.

The excel webapp can deal with sheet protection and then it forces you to open in excel without the download.